# How can I route traffic through a custom proxy to my kubernetes container?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

So we've got a big site with 1 **nginx** config that handles everything! This includes SSL.

At the moment, the config is setup to route all traffic for **subdomain.ourdomain.com** to our **exposed kubernetes service**.

When I visit **subdomain.ourdomain.com**, it returns a **502 Bad Gateway**. I've triple checked that the service inside my kubernetes pod is running properly. I'm pretty certain there is something wrong with the kubernetes config I'm using.

So what I've done:

1. Created kubernetes service
2. Exposed it using type LoadBalancer
3. Added the correct routing to our nginx config for our subdomain

This is what the `kubectl get services returns`:

```
users          <cluster_ip>   <external_ip>   80/TCP     12m
```

This is what `kubectl get endpoints returns`:

```
kubernetes     <kub_ip>:443   48d
redis-master   10.0.1.5:6379        48d
redis-slave    10.0.0.5:6379        48d
users          10.0.2.7:80          3m
```

All I want to do is route all traffic through our **nginx** configuration to our kubernetes service?

We tried routing all traffic to our kubernetes container cluster IP, but this didn't work.

Comment: You're using the service's external IP in your nginx config right?

Comment: Perhaps, also add the relevant nginx config that you are using to the question.

Comment: Yeah @kellanburket